# Branch cut of $\sqrt{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

In my complex analysis book, the author defines the $\sqrt{z}$ on the slit plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. I understand this is done because $z^2$ is not injective on the entire complex plane, so we restrict the domain of $z^2$ to $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, and then $z^2$ maps bijectively on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0].$ This particular restriction of the domain to $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ give rise to the principle root function. My question is, why can't we include either the positive or negative real axis in this domain? I understand why $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ wouldn't work, as $(-\infty,0)$ would be mapped to twice, but it seems to me that $z^2:[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\to\mathbb{C}$ would define a bijection and allow us to define $\sqrt{z}$ as single-valued. So why don't we do this?

Comment: With the proposed half-open interval, the square root function is defined on the whole plane, but is discontinuous along the negative real axis. By taking the domain to be the slit plane, the square root is holomorphic throughout its domain.

Comment: Your notation here is a bit off.  Try to come up with a situation where your proposal would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain of $w=f(z)=z^2$ is not restricted to $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ to obtain an inverse. Rather, the interval $[0,\pi ]$ (or $[\pi ,2\pi ]$ is obtained as the image of a bijection from the slit $w$ plane. This map is then a branch of the inverse.

The procedure is as follows:

it's no harder to look at the more general case so let $w=f(z)=z^{n}, \ \text {for }n\in \mathbb N$. Then $f$ maps the sector $0\leq \theta \leq2\pi/n$ onto $\mathbb C$.

To every point on the positive real axis of the $w$ plane there corresponds one point on each of the two rays $\theta =0$ and $\theta =2\pi/n$ in the $z$ plane.  Therefore, except for the positive real axis in the $w-$ plane, the map is bijective.

So we can get a bijection if we "cut" the positive real axis of $w$ plane so that after the cut, the upper edge corresponds to the positive real axis in the $z$ plane and the lower edge corresponds to $\theta =2\pi/n$ in the $z$ plane.

We now simply define $z=w^{1/n}$ to be the inverse of this map. It maps the slit $w$ plane bijectively onto the sector $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi/n$.

It is easy to see that there are sectors $\frac{2\pi k}{n}\leq \theta \leq \frac{2\pi (k+1)}{n}, \quad k=0,1,\cdots n-1$ in the $z$ plane onto which are mapped bijectively, copies of the slit $w$ plane and so we get by this process $n$ "branches" all of which are inverses of $w=z^n$. They map slit copies of $\mathbb C$ onto sectors in the $z$ plane.

A moment's reflection shows that we can take $\textit {any}$ sector that sweeps out an angle $2\pi /n$ in the $z$ plane and the foregoing analysis goes through with very minor modifications.

A nice way to tie all this up is to now glue all these copies together so as to define a injection from the glued copies back to the entire $z$ plane. i.e. consider the Riemann Surface for $w=z^n$.

Comment: I see. So the same kind of procedure applies to the more general power function. I think I may have been somewhat imprecise with my question. I think what I was really trying to get at is, is the purpose of a branch cut in the $w$-plane, really, to make the inverse function continuous, as Andrew suggested? Since you can define $z^2:[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\to\mathbb{C}$ as a bijection, but $\sqrt{z}$ is not continuous at any point on $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: @user153582: the inverse will not be continuous at any point $w$ along the cut because the limits from above and below correspond to points on the lower and upper rays of the sector. When you pass to the Riemann surface,  however you do get coninuity assured by the gluing procedure.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: @user153582: no problem. I am no expert, so it helps me as well to write this all out. By the way, the map $z^2:[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\to\mathbb{C}$ is indeed a bijection, but if you look at the construction I outlined and then consider how the Riemann surface is obtained, you will see that you need your inverse to map slit copies of $\mathbb C$ ot sectors of the form $\frac{2\pi k}{n}\leq \theta \leq \frac{2\pi (k+1)}{n}, \quad k=0,1,\cdots n-1$ that is, both rays included, so that overlapping edges of adjacent sectors may be glued together.

Comment: @Driver8 "Therefore, except for the positive real axis in the $w-$plane, the map is bijective." This is a false statement.